# Encrypting SALTEDHASHED weblogic password in java

Tags: passwords, weblogic, encryption

How to encrypt SALTEDHASHED password (used by Weblogic) in java?

I need to be able to hash passwords in exactly the same way as WebLogic's authenticator does. Preferably without using WebLogic's library.

30 minutes later..
I've read some documentation and if I don't know the value of the salt I can't encrypt the password in the same way of weblogic.

So, the new question is:
where weblogic stores the value of the salt? It's unique for each password or it associated one to one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Where does weblogic stores the value of the salt? It's unique for each password or it associated one to one?

The value of the salt is stored in `SerializedSystemIni.dat`, the domain's password salt file. The salt is unique for each [encrypted](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/admin_ref/utils.html#wp1209592) password. You should use `weblogic.security.Encrypt`...

Comment: We have deployed the application that checks user's credentials on a weblogic server and then we call the authenticate method of a class in the weblogic.lib!
That's works... :|

Comment: Not sure I get your comment. Maybe I missed something in the original question...